# How does Wireshark gets all the information from a HTTP Post Method ? (string-format)

Tags: http, networking, wireshark, packets

What is the exact string format used by Wireshark in order to 'sniff' the user-inserted values in a HTTP POST-method ( a login-form with username, password for example) ?

To be more specific, I was curious what is the HTTP Header Field that allows that because in the output from the Wireshark that Header Field name is missing (I can see all the others - such as User-Agent, Content-Type, Content-Length and so on).

I was wondering because I am a httpry user and I was curious if there's a possibility of 'cutting the man in the middle' (My .dump files created with httpry can be opened in Wireshark and I can get all the information I need from there - after applying the filters of course).

Don't get me wrong, I know that Wireshark is a much more complex mechanism than httpry but I am just curious how Wireshark can give that desired output using the .dump  from httpry and if I can get the result (even in hexazecimal) in httpry.

Thanks for your patience and I hope that I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about an [HTML form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html).  If the form is being submitted with a POST request, then [the "form data set" is sent as the message](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13), which means it's in the body of the POST request.

That means that Content-Type and Content-Length are the relevant headers; Content-Type indicates the format used for the data, and Content-Length indicates the number of bytes of data in that format.  The form data is *not* in a header.

So you'll have to parse the request line to determine that it's a POST, and then parse the following lines, looking for Content-Type and Content-Length (and possibly some encoding headers as well), until you see a blank line.  The blank line is the end of the header lines; what follows it is the body of the request.  That's what you need to process as the form data.  If there's a Content-Length field, parse exactly that many bytes of body; otherwise, parse until a TCP FIN (end of data stream).  If chunked or compressed encoding is being used, you'l have to handle them.